# php - I want to make one subdomain cookieless

Tags: php

I have multiple sub domains on my website. I want to make one of them cookieless to serve static content. I use this line of code, but it affect on all subdomains...

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

As general rule, there is no way for exclude an specific subdomain of set/receive cookies.

The best alternative is to use different first level domains (You may have seen various famous sites using this technique, for example yimg.com for Yahoo assets)